# What tex symbol is used for the "consider" word?

Tags: symbols

Years ago I attended lectures where the lecturer used a "consider" quantifier. The symbol was very handy, and now I wish to type it in TeX. The problem is that I fail to type it or even guess its name. What tex symbol is used for the "consider" word? And what other names does it have, if any? I've attached the image
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Have you tried https://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html ?

Comment: @Mensch, Thank you for the link, it's new for me! Now I'm trying several drawings, but the best for now `\lessdot` lacks a vertical line. Also, I found the unicode's `⦝` ("Measured Right Angle with Dot", U+299D), but it's orientation is 45-deg. wrong

Comment: You could use U+023FF ⏿ with lualatex or xelatex and a font that has it (Unicode "`Observer Eye Symbol`") Or more commonly available U+207p `⩹` (Unicode `Less-than with circle inside`)

Comment: The way you use this symbol, it's not a quantifier, though this symbol is a variable binder as well. Write “Let“ or “let” instead. Purely logically (style aside), “let” is standard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are fine with a curved line you can superimpose `\sphericalangle` with `\cdot`. Otherwise... picture mode!

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\newcommand*{\considerA}{{\sphericalangle\mkern-8.5mu{\cdot}\mkern5.5mu}}

\usepackage{pict2e}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\considerB}{{\mkern2mu\mathpalette\consider@B\relax\mkern2mu}}
\newcommand*{\consider@B}[2]{%
   \setbox\z@=\hbox{$#1\mkern18mu$}%
   \unitlength\wd\z@
   \vcenter{%
      \hbox{%
         \begin{picture}(.6,.5)
         \roundcap\roundjoin
         \linethickness{\fontdimen8
             \ifx#1\displaystyle\textfont\else
             \ifx#1\textstyle\textfont\else
             \ifx#1\scriptstyle\scriptfont\else
             \scriptscriptfont\fi\fi\fi\thr@@}% default frac rule width
         \Line(.6,0)(0,.25)(.6,.5)
         \Line(.5,.042)(.5,.458)
         \put(.35,.25){\circle*{.1}}
         \end{picture}%
         }%
      }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$X \considerA X$
$\scriptstyle X \considerA X$
$\scriptscriptstyle X \considerA X$

$X \considerB X$
$\scriptstyle X \considerB X$
$\scriptscriptstyle X \considerB X$

\end{document}
```

[image]